# Derivative of log-determinant of square root of a matrix

Tags: statistics, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $\Sigma$ be a symmetric positive-definite matrix. We then denote $\Sigma^{1/2}$ as its square root so that $(\Sigma^{1/2})^2=\Sigma$. I am wondering if 
$$
\frac{\partial\ln[\det(\Sigma^{1/2}A\Sigma^{1/2})]}{\partial\Sigma}
$$
has a closed-form solution. Here, $A$ is a diagonal matrix with appropriate dimension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that$$\det(\Sigma^{1/2}A\Sigma^{1/2})=\det(A\Sigma^{1/2}\Sigma^{1/2})=\det(A\Sigma)=\det A\det\Sigma.$$[Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula) implies $\partial_\Sigma\det\Sigma=(\operatorname{adj}\Sigma)^T$, so $$\partial_\Sigma\ln\det(\Sigma^{1/2}A\Sigma^{1/2})=\partial_\Sigma\ln\det\Sigma=(\det\Sigma)^{-1}(\operatorname{adj}\Sigma)^T.$$

Comment: Why is it true for the first equation? Does it mean it is independent on the matrix A?

Comment: @Eggplant It's an application of $\det XY=\det X+\det Y$; see edit.

Comment: Addition or multiplication of dets?

Comment: @lux Forgive the typo. The log-determinants add, so can be differentiated separately.

Comment: $ \det XY= \det X \det Y$.  So, $\log \det XY = \log \det X + \log \det Y$.

Comment: Yes this is correct, but perhaps as it stands it may be confusing for the op

Comment: Thanks very much! I got the point! How about the differential $\partial_{\Sigma} (\Sigma^{1/2}A\Sigma^{1/2})^{-1}$. I am also confused whether it has a closed-form expression.

Comment: @Eggplant Just to double-check, are you trying to differentiate a matrix as stated or its log-determinant instead? Be warned in general the derivative of a matrix with respect to a matrix is a rank-$4$ tensor, which you might not have studied.

Comment: @J.G. Sorry for the confusion. I am trying to differentiate two matrices. The first is the log-determinant as shown in the problem. Another is $a^T(\Sigma^{1/2}A\Sigma^{1/2})^{-1}b$, where $a$ and $b$ are column vectors with appropriate length. I know the first differential has closed form based on your answer. I am just wondering if I can also get the closed-form expression for the $\partial_{\Sigma} a^T(\Sigma^{1/2}A\Sigma^{1/2})^{-1}b$

Comment: @Eggplant I recommend you ask a separate question about that.

Comment: @J.G. Thanks very much.